How to record automatically with Google Meet API?
I am building web app with Google Meet API using nodejs.
My web service needs to hold a meeting in GoogleMeet with anonymous participants and automatically save the recording.
But I can't find any clue for auto recording over Google Meet API.
Now I can make Google Meet space with api.
But auto recording is not supported.
Can anyone give me a hint to solve this?
Thanks in advance. :)

Sounds like a security issue. In the states at least, some are 1 party consent and some are 2 party consent. I doubt there's a way to automatically record for these and other reasons.

Yap, that could be really security issue. Thanks for the comment. :)

In my opinion, Google Meet API does not support direct programmatic access to start or stop recordings automatically. The recording feature in Google Meet is designed to be manually controlled via the Google Meet UI, and there is no API endpoint provided by Google to start or stop recording.
How about using third party tools such as Selenium which can interact with browser and stimulate user actions(such as clicking record button).

Thank you for your reply. Selenium is not a suitable option for the moment. I'm gonna try to change meeting solution. Thanks :)
